# Is there a "round-trip" x86/64 disassembler/assembler combo available?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

Microsoft's Macro Assembler and DumpBin are great tools, but you can't feed DumpBin's results into MASM -- it lacks some info (like exception handling directives) which are necessary for correct assembly, and the syntax also seems to have issues.

Is there any x86/64 disassembler that can produce disassembled code which can be assembled **without modification** back into *exactly* the original executable?

Comment: I think you need to expand the question. There are many disassemblers that will simply convert everything in a binary  (code, data, resources, etc) into assembler which can then be reassembled back to the same binary - after all, it's just a sequence of bits. I assume what you're actually asking for is a disassembler which is capable of "interpreting" binaries at a higher level to produce useful output (such as code + data sections, etc) in such a form which an assembler can use.

Comment: @adelphus: Yeah I'm pretty much looking for something like `dumpbin`, except one which outputs in a format that can be fed into an assembler. `dumpbin` outputs all the necessary information, it's just a shame that the format is so weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless we're talking about very simple, flat executables like .COM in DOS, I doubt it. These days executables contain a lot of stuff besides raw code and its data and fully extracting all the components and putting them back together isn't something very straightforward or universally supported.

And then, don't forget that many instructions can be encoded in several different ways (e.g. `mov ax, 0`). To cope with the encoding ambiguity you should explicitly assemble `db 0b8h, 0, 0` or `db 0c7h, 0c0h, 0, 0` instead of `mov ax, 0`. db's you can assemble without a loss.

Comment: Well I mean `dumpbin` dumps out pretty much everything I want -- it's just not in a format usable for any assembler. But it seems to disassembler pretty well, and doesn't seem to omit anything... so it doesn't look very impossible to do, right?

Comment: Not impossible, it's just that this is rarely needed (if at all) and I'm pretty sure there are no tools that can do it out of the box.